# group array of php objects by object property

Tags: php

I have a php object (book) with 3 properties: `name, category, description`
I then have a list of these `book` objects in an array.
I want to create a new associative array for these objects grouped by `category`.

Say I have 4 book objects in an array called `$books`

```
name    category  description
==================================
book1   cat1     this is book 1
book2   cat1     this is book 2
book3   cat2     this is book 3
book4   cat3     this is book 4
```

how can I create an associative array called `$categories`

```
$categories['cat1'] = array(book1, book2)
$categories['cat2'] = array(book2)
$categories['cat3'] = array(book3)
```

where book? is the book object and not the word

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Like this:

```
foreach($books as $book)
{ 
    $categories[$book->category][] = $book;
}
```

Comment: If you've found this answer and aren't immediately aware of what it's doing -- it's creating a new array (named `$categories`) with a key for every value of `$book->category`. Each key's value is an array of `$book` objects that correspond to that `$book->category`. I'd make an ASCII picture if it wouldn't look like mud in this comment.

Comment: And if you want to sort the categories, that's extra: `ksort($categories);` See http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Answer (score 5):

Simply loop the array of objects into a new array with the key being the category:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $entity)
{
    if(!isset($newArray[$entity->category]))
    {
         $newArray[$entity->category] = array();
    }

    $newArray[$entity->category][] = $entity;
}
```

Is this what you was looking for ?

Explanation of the code:

```
/*
    * Create a new blank array, to store the organized data in.
*/
$newArray = array();

/*
    * Start looping your original dataset
*/
foreach($array as $entity)
{

    /*
        * If the key in the new array does not exists, set it to a blank array.
    */
    if(!isset($newArray[$entity->category]))
    {
         $newArray[$entity->category] = array();
    }

    /*
        * Add a new item to the array, making shore it falls into the correct category / key
    */
    $newArray[$entity->category][] = $entity;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with [ouzo goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies):

```
 $categories = Arrays::groupBy($books, Functions::extractField('category'));
```

See: http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utils/arrays.html#groupby

Answer (score 1):

```
$categories = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($books); $i++){
    if (isset($categories[$books[$i]->category]) == false)
        $categories[$books[$i]->category] = array();

    $categories[$books[$i]->category][] = $books[$i]
}
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$categories = array();
foreach ($books as $book){

  if (!array_key_exists($book->category , $categories))
     $categories[$book->category] = array();

  $categories[$book->category][] = $book;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

```
$categories = array();
foreach ($books as $book) {

    $categories[$book['category']][] = $book;

}
```

Comment: Unlike JavaScript, you cannot access object properties with the array `[propertyName]` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but a bit more complicated with wordpress and metavalues/metakeys (where $results was an array of associative arrays fetched from a $wpdb->get_results() query.

This was my solution adapted to your problem:

```
$categories = array();
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $id =  $row['category'];
    $description = $row['category'];
    $name = $row['name']
    if (!isset($categories[$id])) {
        $categories[$id] = array();
    }
    $categories[$id] = array_merge($categories[$id], 'description'=>$description , 'name'=>$name);
}
```

Then you can run another for loop to get each array from the categories array:

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    var_dump($category);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group objects by getting key from specific method with or without additional arguments, you can use [this library](https://github.com/minwork/array) method:

```
Arr::groupObjects(array $objects, string $method, ...$args): array
```