# Same value is repeating multiple times in for each

Tags: php

I am using PHP curl to get data from an API. I want to print main heading only 1 time, but now it is printing more than one time if there is .. Following is my code.
I want the results as in following structure

Marketing

1. Technical writer USA. read more link
2. Technical writer USA. read more link

Now am getting data as

Marketing

Technical writer USA. read more link

Marketing

Technical writer kakandu. read more link

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

    <?php

        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.example.com/c/1832/offers",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Authorization: Bearer R0ssstYYXBTWG1Ddm5wbUgzT3pwa214Zz09"
        ),
        ));

        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
        curl_close($curl);
?>
<?php 
// echo "<pre>";
// var_dump($response);
   foreach($response->offers as $key=>$value){
      echo '<div>
      <h1><u>'.$value->department.'</u></h1> <br> 
      <p>'.$value->title.'</p><br>
      <p>'.$value->location.'</p>
      <a target="_blank" href='.$value->url.'>Read More </a>
      </div>';
   }
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Kindly help me

Comment: does all `$value->department` has the same value?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65192797/edit) to show an example of the data received.

Comment: Without seeing an example of the original data and how you'd like to format the result, this is impossible to answer

Comment: @Phil You can directly copy this in code, it will shows original data

Comment: People willing to help you should not need to make random API calls in order to find out what the data looks like. As to my second point, only you know the result you want which you have not communicated in your question. Please edit your question to provide all the information required. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [group array of php objects by object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263827/group-array-of-php-objects-by-object-property)

Comment: @Phil, can you please demostarte and edit for me

Comment: What you want, is called a [control break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break), and quite simple to implement. You just need to compare the relevant criterion (here, the department) of the current record with that of the previous one - and depending on whether they differ or are the same, you output the department heading or not. (Your data must of course be properly sorted by that criterion to begin with.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to group the results by *department* before displaying them.

What you can do is transform the data to a nested data structure, eg

```
{
  [ department ]: [{
    title: "Title",
    location: "Location",
    url: "https://..."
  }, {
    //...
  }]
}
```

Something like this

```php
// same as your code above up to this point
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
curl_close($curl);

// Group results by department name
$offersByDepartment = [];
foreach ($response->offers as $offer) {
    $offersByDepartment[$offer->department][] = [
        "title"    => $offer->title,
        "location" => $offer->location,
        "url"      => $offer->url
    ];
}

$response = null; // free up response

foreach ($offersByDepartment as $department => $offers) : ?>
<div>
  <h1><?= $department ?></h1>
  <ol>
    <?php foreach ($offers as $offer) : ?>
      <li>
        <?= htmlspecialchars($offer["title"]) ?>
        <?= htmlspecialchars($offer["location"]) ?>.
        <a href="<?= htmlspecialchars($offer["url"]) ?>" target="_blank">
          Read more
        </a>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </ol>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/rpgEg

Comment: Yup very thanks, but since they are providing data in this format, how can we done that

Comment: @XavierIssac I have no idea what you're asking, sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

    <?php

        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.recruitee.com/c/1832/offers",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Authorization: Bearer R0tYYXBTWG1Ddm5wbUgzT3pwa214Zz09"
        ),
        ));

        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
        curl_close($curl);
?>
<?php 
// echo "<pre>";
// var_dump($response);
  $grouped_jobs = array();
   foreach($response->offers as $key=>$value){
      $grouped_jobs[$value->department][] = array('title'=> $value->title, 'location'=> $value->location, 'url'=> $value->url);

   }
   echo "<pre>";
   
   foreach($grouped_jobs as $key=>$value){

       echo '<div>
        <h1><u>'.$key.'</u></h1> <br>';
        foreach($value as $job) {
            echo '<p>'.$job['title'].'</p><br>
        <p>'.$job['location'].'</p>
        <a target="_blank" href='.$job['url'].'>Read More </a>';
       
        }
        echo '</div>';  
   }

?>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 options to do this.

1. Take out the `<h1>` out of the loop, get the value from the first item of the array
2. Add a condition to print the `<h1>` part. (e.g `if($key==0)`)